# I don't feel like creating this riddle today

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My suffix can be found all around the world and many have fought over them.

My prefix is all in favor of this riddle.

My Infix sounds like the coat of arms.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A little unsure but I think it may be

> Procrastination

My suffix can be found all around the world and many have fought over them.

> Nation

My prefix is all in favor of this riddle.

> Pro

My Infix sounds like the coat of arms.

> Crast sounds like *Crest*, which could be a synonym for a coat of arms.

Title

> Seems like procrastination would lead you to make a riddle like this.

Comment: Wauw I don't think I ever seen a riddle solved this fast :p, good job! Maybe I made it a bit too easy, I'll make sure to create a harder one next time.

Comment: It's 'them' , so it must be 'n\*t\*\*ns'. And the infox 'i ' is unaccounted for :-(

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> procrastinate

which is what the asker is relation to in the title.

My suffix can be found all around the world and many have fought over them.

> I have no clue

My prefix is all in favor of this riddle.

> pro - positive prefix also meaning being in favour of something

My Infix sounds like the coat of arms.

> crast - sounds and looks almost like crest, which is a piece of heraldry (among other things)

Comment: ninja'd by hexomino